# Moderator links

Tags: script, hyperlinks

Adds some extra links to posts and userpages for convenience

For a userpage, all links from the "info" mod menu, except "privileges" is displayed along in the "mod"/"edit"/"prefs"/"flair menu.

For posts, it adds a link to the comment history/flag history. It also adds a link to the revhistory for posts which don't have a direct link (from the "last edited by").

### Installation

- [Click here to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/Modlinks.user.js). Will work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey). See [this page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) if you have trouble, or want to install on Opera/Safari/IE.
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/Modlinks.user.js)

Comment: Awesome, awesome script! I like how the non-moderator links are also visible on other sites!